# CSS3 with Unsorted list

Tags: html, css

[image: screen dump]

As you can see in the image above, the menu (left) does not display correctly. 
I would like to make the menu on the (right)

I have made `float: right`, `right: 0px;`, `margin-right:0px;`. All of these do not work and `float:right` will display off the screen (the page was extended to the right)

[image]

Code: (HTML)

```
<div id="navwrap">
<ul class="rightmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">IT Helpdesk</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Hub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logoff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Code: (CSS)

```
#navwrap    { 
    width:100%; 
    height:30px;    
    margin:0;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#4c4e5a;
}

.rightmenu, .rightmenu ul, .rightmenu li, .rightmenu a { 
margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: none;   outline: none;  border: 0px;
}

.rightmenu { background-color: #4c4e5a;float: right; }
.rightmenu li { position: relative; list-style: none; float: left; display: block;}

.rightmenu li a {
    display: block; padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;  color: #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #4c4e5a;  text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942; border-right: 1px solid #393942;
}

.rightmenu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.rightmenu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }  
.rightmenu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; } 
.rightmenu ul li:last-child a { border: none; } 

.rightmenu ul {
    position: absolute;  top: 30px; left: 0;   
    opacity: 0;  background-color: #4c4e5a;
}

.rightmenu li:hover > ul {  opacity: 1; }  
.rightmenu ul li {height:0; overflow:hidden; padding: 0;   }   
.rightmenu li:hover > ul li {  height: 30px;  overflow: visible;padding: 0;} 
.rightmenu ul li a {  width: 200px;   padding: 4px 0 4px 0px;   border: none; }
```

Comment: `right: 0;` goes with `position: absolute;`, have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following CSS. What you need to do is right aligning the last sub-menu.

```
#navwrap    { 
    width:100%; 
    height:30px;    
    margin:0;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#4c4e5a;
}

.rightmenu, .rightmenu ul, .rightmenu li, .rightmenu a { 
margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: none;   outline: none;  border: 0px;
}

.rightmenu { background-color: #4c4e5a;float: right; }
.rightmenu li { position: relative; list-style: none; float: left; display: block;}

.rightmenu li a {
    display: block; padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;  color: #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #4c4e5a;  text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942; border-right: 1px solid #393942;
}

.rightmenu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.rightmenu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }  
.rightmenu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; } 
.rightmenu ul li:last-child a { border: none; } 

.rightmenu ul {
    position: absolute;  top: 30px; left: 0;   
    opacity: 0;  background-color: #4c4e5a;
}

.rightmenu li:last-child ul
{
  left: auto;
  right: 0
}


.rightmenu li:hover > ul {  opacity: 1; }  
.rightmenu ul li {height:0; overflow:hidden; padding: 0;   }   
.rightmenu li:hover > ul li {  height: 30px;  overflow: visible;padding: 0;} 
.rightmenu ul li a {  white-space: nowrap;   border: none; }
```

The changes are:

```
.rightmenu li:last-child ul
{
  left: auto;
  right: 0
}

.rightmenu ul li a {  white-space: nowrap;   border: none; }
```

Comment: with a little amendment: `left:auto right:0` could resolve my question. ths.

Answer (score 0):

`.rightmenu ul li a {` the 200px value wont do so much here, `a` is a inline element. try setting it to `display: block`

Comment: thanks for comment, please see the capture "C", it was the result.